# How to upload files using cUrl from an ASP.NET MVC3 website?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, curl

I need to upload a file to RackSpace's Cloud Files.

At their API page they have an example in cUrl, does anyone know how to implement that in C#?

Any north would be much appreciated since my search is not being helpful, all I found even here were codes that looked a lot like a regular upload.

Here's the example I need working in C#:

```
Upload File to Container
curl -X PUT -T screenies/hello.jpg -D - \
-H "ETag: 805120e285a7ed28f74024422fe3594" \
-H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" \
-H "X-Auth-Token: fc81aaa6-98a1-9ab0-94ba-aba9a89aa9ae" \
-H "X-Object-Meta-Screenie: Hello World" \

https://storage.clouddrive.com/v1/CF_xer7_343/
images/hello.jpg

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Thu, 09 July 2009 17:03:36 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 0
ETag: 805120e285a7ed28f74024422fe3594
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Just to be clear, I don't want anyone to do my work for me, I just need some tutorial or north as I said.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use either `HttpWebRequest` to send the PUT request to the service or the newer `HttpClient` api

See a sample below.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Auth_User", "your_username");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Auth-Key", "your_api_key");

 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("image/pjpeg"));

var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);
var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);

 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("image/pjpeg"));
 var content = new StreamContent(ms);


 var response = client.PutAsync("YOUR_RACKSPACE_URI", content);
```

Comment: So I would send the file in a regular way, only using PUT as request method?

Comment: I'm not sure how rackspace cloud files works but i guess they'll be some sort of auth going on before you can upload.

Comment: They do, and I know I'll have to use NetworkCredentials for that. But I just want to confirm that it will be a regular upload, right? I was just searching for HttpClient and saw it for WCF, does it work for non-WCF?

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer, I'll try that right now and will accept the answer if that works. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @eestein i've updated my answer with a sample which may help.

Comment: I was getting there, but you DEFINETILY helped :) Speacially with the DefaulRequestHeaders part. thanks a lot :)